# How to have a static board on tic tac toe?

Tags: python

I was trying to build a tic-tac-toe programme, however, I want to understand how to have a static board when user inputs "O" or "X" or when I just want to see the board.

Edit: Outputs appear weird in the question, the first one is a wonky board since it has inputs, whereas the 2nd example is clean.

e.g.

```
theBoard = {'top-L': 'O', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'O',
            'mid-L': 'X', 'mid-M': 'X', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'X'}

def printBoard(board):
    print(board['top-L'] + ' |' + board['top-M'] + ' |' + board['top-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['mid-L'] + ' |' + board['mid-M'] + ' |' + board['mid-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['low-L'] + ' |' + board['low-M'] + ' |' + board['low-R'])
```

output:

```
O |O |O
-+-+-
X |X | 
-+-+-
  |  |X
```

2nd e.g.

```
theBoard = {'top-L': '', 'top-M': '', 'top-R': '',
            'mid-L': '', 'mid-M': '', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ''}

def printBoard(board):
    print(board['top-L'] + ' |' + board['top-M'] + ' |' + board['top-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['mid-L'] + ' |' + board['mid-M'] + ' |' + board['mid-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['low-L'] + '|' + board['low-M'] + '|' + board['low-R'])
```

output:

```
 | |
-+-+-
 | | 
-+-+-
 | |
```

So is there a way to make it aesthetically pleasing all the time? or I have to use another model?

Further issues: 
You can see that in the last line inside def on the 2nd example there's no space in the '|' which i needed to adjust, however on the first 2 '|' I needed to put a space ' |' which I have no idea why.

Comment: There is an edit button below your question, above the comments

Comment: what do you mean by static board?

Comment: That doesn't move all over the place, since when i put "X" or "O" the board moves.

Comment: use `tabulate` module

Comment: Your cells are all two characters wide: one for an `X`, `O`, or space, and an additional space. Your horizontal lines, though, all use *one* hyphen per cell, not two. `print("--+--+--")`

Comment: I think the dict with English words is a rather ungainly way to represent a TTT board. Consider using a couple of numbers (one for X and one for O) and bit manipulation, a 2d list or numpy array/matrix. By representing the data nicely, you automatically have far less trouble doing things like printing in a straightforward and elegant manner.

Comment: @chepner I tried to use  print("--+--+--") but the output is still not smooth

Comment: Your second example is also inconsistent in using 0 or 1 space for an empty cell, or whether you output an additional space with each `|`. Fix the horizontal lines in your first example, which is otherwise fine.

Comment: @chepner I adjusted it but the output doesn't match what I'm expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to output an extra space next to each vertical line, your horizontal lines need to account for that. I would actually add a blank space on *both* sides of the marker.

```
theBoard = {'top-L': 'O', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'O',
            'mid-L': 'X', 'mid-M': 'X', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'X'}

def printBoard(board):
    print(' {} | {} | {} '.format(board['top-L'], board['top-M'], board['top-R']))
    print('---+---+---')
    print(' {} | {} | {} '.format(board['mid-L'], board['mid-M'], board['mid-R']))
    print('---+---+---')
    print(' {} | {} | {} '.format(board['low-L'], board['low-M'], board['low-R']))
```

Then

```
>>> printBoard(theBoard)
 O | O | O
---+---+---
 X | X |
---+---+---
   |   | X
```

You also need to remember that each element of the board *must* be a single character, either `X`, `O`, or a space.

Comment: Yeah this looks much better. Does printing the an empty board gives the same result but without the X and O?

Comment: As long as your board represents an empty cell using a space and not an empty string, yes. Any single character has the same width (assuming you are using a monospace font; all bets are off with proportional fonts).

Answer (score 1):

wrapping each element with extra space seem to help the presentation a bit.

```
theBoard = {'top-L': 'O', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'O',
            'mid-L': 'X', 'mid-M': 'X', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'X'}

separator = '+'.join(('---',)*3)

def printBoard(board):
    print(' ' + ' | '.join([board['top-L'], board['top-M'], board['top-R']]))
    print(separator)
    print(' ' + ' | '.join([board['mid-L'], board['mid-M'], board['mid-R']]))
    print(separator)
    print(' ' + ' | '.join([board['low-L'], board['low-M'], board['low-R']]))


printBoard(theBoard)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental design problem here. The data structure:

```
theBoard = {'top-L': 'O', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'O',
            'mid-L': 'X', 'mid-M': 'X', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'X'}
```

is extremely awkward to manipulate, even with Python 3.6 dict ordering and in spite of (or because of) its semantically named keys. The printing problem you're facing seems to be a side effect of this awkward representation that requires "knowing" all of the magic string keys for each square, so it's pretty much impossible to iterate over it by rows and columns or index into it naturally with `0..2` numbers for rows and columns.

While fixing your printing is the topic of the question, I suspect you have other code that might be pretty ungainly elsewhere in your application.

Consider using a data structure like a 2d list to represent the board. Here's how this might work as a very simple sketch (no error handling or win checking has been added, but this design will be more conducive to writing those things than the current approach):

```
class TTTBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [[None] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
        self.sides = "XO"
        self.ply = 0

    def move(self, row, col):
        if not self.board[row][col]:
            self.board[row][col] = self.sides[self.ply%2]
            self.ply += 1
            return True

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n---+---+---\n".join(" " + " | ".join(x if x else " " for x in row)
                                                       for row in self.board)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    board = TTTBoard()
    moves = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [2, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

    for position in moves:
        board.move(*position)
        print(board, "\n")
```

Output:

```
   | X |
---+---+---
   |   |
---+---+---
   |   |

   | X | O
---+---+---
   |   |
---+---+---
   |   |

   | X | O
---+---+---
   |   |
---+---+---
   | X |

   | X | O
---+---+---
 O |   |
---+---+---
   | X |

   | X | O
---+---+---
 O | X |
---+---+---
   | X |
```

For the sake of answering your question and for comparison, you could "gather" the board in your original representation into a 2d list, then use the same nested `join` as above:

```
theBoard = {'top-L': 'O', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'O',
            'mid-L': 'X', 'mid-M': 'X', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'X'}
vals = list(theBoard.values())
board = [[vals[i+j*3] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
print("\n---+---+---\n".join(" " + " | ".join(row) for row in board))
```

This works in Python 3.6+, but having to do this transformation, or indexing into the dictionary again and again by name for each square is less appealing than choosing a usable data structure from the start.